# user defined printf failed to print float value

Tags: c

I have a task to do which is to use similar function like printf  to format & print float to two decimal places by using %f formatter.

I have tried but the output is blank. May you please point out where I am making mistake.

```
void printf_for_float(char * fmt, ...) {
    char * p;
    float n;
    va_list v1_float;
    va_start(v1_float, fmt);
    for (p = fmt; *p != '\0'; p++) {
        if (*p != '%') {
            putchar(*p);
            continue;
        }
        p++;
        switch(*p) {
            case 'f':
            printf(" we are in float area \n" );
                n = va_arg(v1_float, float);
                n =  convert_to_float(n);
                puts(convert_float_str(n));
            break;
            case '%': 
                putchar('%');
            break;
        }
    }
    va_end(v1_float);
}

float convert_to_float(float val) {
    return(floorf(val * 100) / 100);
}

char * convert_float_str(float val) {
    printf(" the float val in funct convert== %f", val);
    char a[sizeof(val)];
    memcpy(a, &val, sizeof(float));
    printf("the value is %s", a);
    return a;
}

int main() {
    float test = 64.5555;
    printf_for_float("\nmy test = %f", test);
    return 0;
}
```

**RESULT**

- Actual o/p 64.550003
- Expected o/p 64.56 or 64.55

Comment: `float` is implicitly converted to `double` when passed to a vararg list... so you probably want to be pulling out a `double`, not a float.

Comment: Your code should include a `main` function that shows the problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if( *p=='%' )` should read `if( *p != '%' )`.

You want to print out characters that are not `%`, and enter the switch when you do encounter a `%`.

What's actually happening is that you enter your switch statement for all the non-`%` characters and there's no `case` for them so nothing happens.

---

The `convert_float_str` function is full of bugs too. It needs a complete re-design.

Firstly, you return a pointer to a local array. When the function returns `a` is destroyed, leaving a dangling pointer being returned.

Secondly you do not make any attempt to format the float as a string. Instead you just copy the bytes of the float to another memory location.

Comment: Thanks Matt for help, I will re-design it , I cannot use snprintf as it requires %f .

Comment: @samprat yes, it seems that the main part of the assignment is to write this code that will output the decimal representation of the float.

Answer (score 0):

The output is blank because the for loop increments p to point to the f (when the right time comes) and then code inside the loop increments p *again* before *p could refer to the 'f' in the switch.